# How could it be that a noun (aircraft and ship) can get a pronoun of "she"?

Tags: pronouns

I saw a [national geographic video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5uAwLamVVz4) and the announcer said (39:25) on the **ship** building that "the super-tanker is not what she was a few months ago... Now she's painted".

The same thing I saw in a [national geographic video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=845w8O4T9v8) (0:03) on **aircraft**: "she is the latest model.."

Therefor I am wondering why this ship or aircraft get the pronoun "she"?

Comment: It is traditional to refer to ships (and boats in general) as "she", even if they are named after men.

Comment: What @Mick said. But it's becoming less common by the decade, so my advice would be to look to the future and stick with ***it*** for all such contexts. If you use ***she*** today, many people will either think you're a bit old-fashioned, or assume you have something of a nautical background.